# Getting duplicate records in Oracle with CLOB attribute

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am getting duplicate records in my Oracle SQL Developer IDE whenever I am querying with this statement:

```
SELECT currency.currency_story.story_id, 
       currency.currency_story.datetimestamp,
       currency.currency_story.headline, 
       currency.currency_story_body.body
FROM 
       currency.currency_story INNER JOIN 
       currency.currency_story_body ON 
       currency.currency_story.story_id = currency.currency_story_body.story_id
WHERE 
       currency.currency_story.datetimestamp > '18-Oct-12' AND  
       SUBSTR(currency.currency_story.story_id,10,4) > '1825' 
ORDER BY 
       currency.currency_story.datetimestamp ASC
```

So after running the bottom statement for both the tables (currency_story & currency_story_body) I am getting 0 rows fetched out:

```
    select currency.currency_story_body.story_id
    from currency.currency_story_body 
    group by currency.currency_story_body.story_id
    having count(*) > 1
```

Same I did for the currency_story table too and I got 0 rows fetched. Now I know that there are no duplicate records in each table. So I am guessing my JOIN is **wrong**? But I dont see flaw in it?

This is my execution plan:

[image: Execution Plan]

My `currency.currency_story_body.body` is a `CLOB` and **story_id** is **NOT** a primary key. What should I do here?

Comment: Since `story_id` is not a `PRIMARY KEY`, are you sure its value is unique within both tables?

Comment: I am sorry I am not handling the DB. How should I check whether the story_id is a PK or not in Oracle SQL Developer?\

Comment: You don't really need to check if it's PK, just see if there are duplicates: `select currency.currency_story.story_id,         currency.currency_story.datetimestamp,        currency.currency_story.headline from currency.currency_story group by currency.currency_story.story_id,         currency.currency_story.datetimestamp,        currency.currency_story.headline having count(*) > 1`

Comment: 0 rows fetched after running the above statement.

Comment: @Catch, are you sure that these are tables and not views? can you show us the execusion plan for you query?

Comment: @A.B.Cade: Yes! I am sure these are tables and not views. However, I did want to point this out: Its a service where I have the R/O access only. Execution plan is to fetch out the unique records from these two tables and store it in the Sitecore CMS system.

Comment: @Catch, that's not what I meant, what is the Query execution plan ? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b31695/intro.htm#autoId28

Answer (score 0):

If you have two records in currency_story_body which both have the same story_id that would cause duplicates.

You are not using currency_story_body anywhere except in the join, so you could try:

```
SELECT currency.currency_story.story_id, 
   currency.currency_story.datetimestamp,
   currency.currency_story.headline, 
   currency.currency_story.body
FROM 
   currency.currency_story
WHERE 
   currency.currency_story.datetimestamp > '18-Oct-12' AND  
   SUBSTR(currency.currency_story.story_id,10,4) > '1825' 
ORDER BY 
   currency.currency_story.datetimestamp ASC
```

Comment: With the edit, the SQL is no longer valid.  However, the principle may be the same.  The duplicates would then be legitimate.

Comment: Actually he is using `currency_story_body.body` in his `SELECT` statement.